# IPtables don't block IP

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm running Postfix SMTP server. Some hosts trying to connect with wrong passwords.

```
warning: s15393678.onlinehome-server.com[74.208.17.126]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed:
```

I'm adding iptables rule on the the fly to block this IP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 74.208.17.126 -j DROP
```

But it still this host gets connected. I still see in logs this host.  What might be wrong?

```
iptables -L
DROP       all  --  s15393678.onlinehome-server.com  anywhere
```

Comment: can you include the output of `iptables -nvL` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `-I INPUT` instead of `-A INPUT`.

`-A INPUT` is going to add the rule to the bottom of the chain. Meaning that if you have something like `-p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT` before it, the `ACCEPT` is going to match first, and the processing will never get to your `-j DROP` rule.

The `-I INPUT` will add the rule to the top, so it overrides everything else.